# How to set/update environment variables for a lambda function using Node SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables

I know I can specify environment variables when I'm creating a lambda function like this:

```
var params = {
  Code: { /* required */
    ZipFile: new Buffer('...')
  },
  FunctionName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Environment: {
    Variables: {
      '<EnvironmentVariableName>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    }
  },
};
lambda.createFunction(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

But how can I set/update environment variables for a lambda function that already exists? I don't see any parameter for [updateFunctionCode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#updateFunctionCode-property)!

Comment: with a different api call, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionConfiguration.html

Comment: @DanFarrell Thanks. It would be great if you could post that as an answer so I  can flag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a separate API call for updating the lambda runtime config, including the environment.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionConfiguration.html

It also updates the timeout, memory, dead letter queue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After you've changed the environment variable in the console, you can run

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name <YOUR_LAMBDA_NAME> --memory-size <YOUR_LABMDA_MEMORY_LIMIT_DEFAULT_128MB>
```

I don't see the option to execute this command from AWS Console, which is pretty odd.